# Replacing OxyPlot Chart in LongListSelector ItemSource

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, longlistselector, oxyplot

I have a bit of a unique setup on one page in my Windows Phone App that I'm having issues with and I'm not sure if it's an issue with the library I'm using or how I have the page setup. Long story short, on one page I have LongListSelector that displays a single Stacked Bar Chart (using OxyPlot) and then several Stack Panels with some TextBlocks (mostly sales information related to the Chart). What I want to do is when the user clicks on the Bar Chart the Chart will switch to a different Bar Chart (one has Month to date the other is Year to date) while the Stack Panel information stays the same. So far I've been able to get everything setup, but I get an Error when I tap on the Bar Chart stating "This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control." and the app crashes. The way I was trying to switch between different charts was to just replace the ItemSource of the LLS with a different one, so I don't know if that's the problem or if it's just an issue with OxyPlot (from their forums it sounds like the Model doesn't re-render so I may just have to display both charts instead of just one). Here's what I have going on so far:

```
//first create model for MTD Commissions
            PlotModel mtdModel = createMTDModel(mtdValue, mtdGoal);
            //Create the Class Item for mtdGDC for LLS Source List
            ServiceClasses.SalesGDCClass mtdItem = new ServiceClasses.SalesGDCClass();
            mtdItem.model = mtdModel;
            mtdItem.footerText = "Tap to view YTD";
            mtdItem.version = 0;
            //create model for YTD Commissions
            PlotModel ytdModel = createYTDModel(ytdValue, (mtdGoal * 12));
            //create class item for ytdGDC
            ServiceClasses.SalesGDCClass ytdItem = new ServiceClasses.SalesGDCClass();
            ytdItem.model = ytdModel;
            ytdItem.footerText = "Tap to view MTD";
            ytdItem.version = 1;

            List<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass> mtdSource = new List<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass>();
            ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass mtdSalesItem = new ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass()
            {
                type = "Sales",
                key = "Sales",
                salesItem = mtdItem
            };
            mtdSource.Add(mtdSalesItem);
            //create YTD sales Item 
            List<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass> ytdSource = new List<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass>();
            ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass ytdSalesItem = new ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass()
            {
                type = "Sales",
                key = "Sales",
                salesItem = ytdItem
            };
            ytdSource.Add(ytdSalesItem);

            //add each transaction found for the last transaction section
            foreach (var item in transactionList)
            {
                ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass transactionItem = new ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass()
                {
                    type = "Transaction",
                    key = "Last 5 Transactions",
                    transactionItem = item
                };
                mtdSource.Add(transactionItem);
                ytdSource.Add(transactionItem);
            }

            //create to source lists to switch between the MTD and YTD options
            var mtdItemSource = StringKeyGroup<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass>.GetGroups(mtdSource, (ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass c) => c.key);
            var ytdItemSource = StringKeyGroup<ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass>.GetGroups(ytdSource, (ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass c) => c.key);
            salesItemList.ItemsSource = mtdItemSource;
            //add tap action to lls
            salesItemList.SelectionChanged += (delegate(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                //if selected item is null do nothing (such as when the page is loaded)
                if (salesItemList.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass selectedItem = (ServiceClasses.SalesItemsClass)salesItemList.SelectedItem;
                if (selectedItem.type == "Sales")
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("the graph was selected");
                       //in here I was replacing the ItemSource but then it would crash

                }
                //reset the selected item value back to nothing
                salesItemList.SelectedItem = null;
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot replace ItemSource once the plot has been rendered. So, yes that is the problem. I suggest you to delete/hide the previous instance of LineSeries and create a new one in the same PlotModel.

I think there is a Oxyplot example on how to make a line series invisible.

http://resources.oxyplot.org/examplebrowser